# Can I get the Iphone/Android GPS location using the Corona SDK?

Tags: iphone, android, coronasdk

Can I get the Iphone/Android GPS location using the Corona SDK? I want to build an app and I am considering Corona, however I am unsure about whether it can access native features of the iphone and android.

I'm a bit confused as:

http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/faq/#who_is

: states :

Is there a way to call the native OS or link to an external library from Corona?

When you work with Corona, you can only access libraries written in Lua and limited to the features currently supported by the Corona SDK. You cannot link to libraries outside of Lua or access the iOS or Android APIs.

That said, we are constantly extending Corona's APIs to add new features and we welcome user input to guide future development. If you'd like to make suggestions on what we should add next, post it on our Features and Roadmap discussion forum.

Comment: Surely if you're considering it you could take a peek at their website's home page...

Comment: Your edit merely indicates that there's no way to add features that the SDK doesn't already support. As they state quite clearly on the home page, GPS is a supported feature.

Comment: Your time would be better spent sending these questions to the Corona developers, or create an account and download their software to try it out and see whether or not it meets your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their website's home page is pretty clear: http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/

> Native device features.
>
> Use native iOS and Android features like multitouch, GPS, accelerometer, camera, Google Maps, WebKit, software keyboards, and more — it’s all available in Corona. Access social networks like Facebook and Openfeint and services like mobile analytics, with much more coming soon!

Comment: Does Corona let me access the address book too?

Comment: Download the Sample Code - SampleCode/Hardware/GPS does what you want. Might be an Address Book example in there too.